# How do I create a random user agent in Python + Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium, user-agent

How do I create a random user_agent in Chrome?  I am using fake-useragent. [Library here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fake-useragent). The printed output is working but when it seems it is not loading into Chrome.

I have tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = Options()
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,600")
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
ua = UserAgent()
a = ua.random
user_agent = ua.random
print(user_agent)
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://whoer.net/')
```

This does not print a random output each time.

Printed output:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.1 Safari/537.36

Output user_agent according to whoer.net:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
>   like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36

Comment: Are you using the options when you instantiate the driver? Looks like you are not.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have not used the options that's why it doesn't work

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = Options()
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,600")
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
ua = UserAgent()
user_agent = ua.random
print(user_agent)
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://whoer.net/')
driver.quit()
```

After that it works, see the console and browser output

[image: Console output]

[image: Browser output]

Answer (score 6):

A simple way to fake the *User Agent* would be using the `FirefoxProfile()` as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

useragent = UserAgent()
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", useragent.random)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("http://www.whatsmyua.info/")
```

Result of 3 consecutive execution is as follows :

1. First Execution :

   ```
   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 4.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36
   ```
2. Second Execution :

   ```
   Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.517 Safari/537.36
   ```
3. Third Execution :

   ```
   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1309.0 Safari/537.17
   ```