# How to change the displayed operating system information within the useragent using Selenium and Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, user-agent

I'm building a bot that will change it's appearance based on the random user agent I select. I pull from a list of user agents, depending on the one selected, I change the capability of the webdriver and then launch it.

However I'm using https://ipleak.net/ to test, and no matter how many times I run this code my true operating system is still showing (instead of the supposedly spoofed version). Relevant code below, FYI true OS = MacIntel

```
desired_caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
desired_caps['platform'] = user_agent_os

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, desired_capabilities=desired_caps)
browser.get("https://ipleak.net/")
```

Possible values for `user_agent_os` = 'ios', 'windows', 'andriod', '---', 'symbian', 'macos', 'linux' and some others. The value is randomised each time the programme runs.

Comment: I'm wondering if I can do something fancy with Selenium-Wire to the headers, but I don't think that will change the webdriver capability.

Comment: Also I believe the title is misleading, I want to change the operating system information within `platform` to match the `user-agent`, not the other way around

Answer (score 2):

The **platform** property can be extracted from the [WebDriver navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904).

You can use the following line of code to extract the value of `navigator.platform` and on my [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) system:

- Code Block:

  ```
  print("platform: "+driver.execute_script("return navigator.platform;"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  platform: Win32
  ```

The possible values of [Navigator platform Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_platform.asp) are:

- `Mac68K`
- `MacPPC`
- `MacIntel`
- `Linux i686`
- `Linux armv7l`
- `Win32`
- `Win16`
- `WinCE`
- `SunOS`
- `HP-UX`

On the other hand, [UserAgent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49565042/way-to-change-google-chrome-user-agent-in-selenium/49565254#49565254) i.e. `navigator.userAgent` does contain a [os](/questions/tagged/os) information as:

- Code Block:

  ```
  print("userAgent: "+driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36
  ```

---

### Solution

The only way to change the [platform](/questions/tagged/platform) information within [UserAgent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48454949/how-do-i-create-a-random-user-agent-in-python-selenium/48459249#48459249) is to rotate the *UserAgent* by using Python's [`fake_useragent`](https://pypi.org/project/fake-useragent/) module.

Chrome

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

options = Options()
ua = UserAgent()
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={ua.random}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
print("userAgent: "+driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;"))
driver.quit()
```

Result of 3 consecutive execution is as follows :

1. First Execution :

   ```
   userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20130331 Firefox/21.0
   ```
2. Second Execution :

   ```
   userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; AS; rv:11.0) like Gecko
   ```
3. Third Execution :

   ```
   userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.0 Safari/537.36
   ```

Firefox

```
from selenium import webdriver
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

useragent = UserAgent()
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", useragent.random)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\\geckodriver.exe')
print("userAgent: "+driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;"))
driver.quit()
```

Result of 3 consecutive execution is as follows :

1. First Execution :

   ```
   userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36 Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.10
   ```
2. Second Execution :

   ```
   userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1309.0 Safari/537.17
   ```
3. Third Execution :

   ```
   userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36
   ```

---

### tl; dr

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on changing the *useragent* on the fly in:

- [How to change the User Agent using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62490495/how-to-change-the-user-agent-using-selenium-and-python/62491863#62491863)
- [How to change the Google Chrome UserAgent using the ChromeDriver installed through webdriver_manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503203/how-to-change-the-google-chrome-useragent-using-the-chromedriver-installed-throu/62503645#62503645)

Comment: Thanks for your response, very detailed and I appreciate it. What I was actually after was how to change the `platform` value displayed by my computer to each website. Looking to match this to the `os` within `useragent` header.

Comment: @Heartthrob_Rob That's exactly I explained how you need to spoof the `platform` value within the `useragent` header.

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB, I think I may have been unclear above. I am randomising the `useragent` from a list I have extracted. I want to then match my `platform` value to this user_agent. I believe your code above matches my `useragent` to `platform`, I am after the reverse.