# How does one pass the user-agent parameter to Selenium::Chrome?

Tags: selenium, perl, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to set the user-agent parameter in Selenium::Chrome, but am not finding the correct way.  Has anyone successfully done this?

```
my $driver = Selenium::Chrome->new(
    'user-agent' => 'TEST',
    '--user-agent' => 'TEST',
    'chromeOptions' => {
        prefs => {
            'user-agent' => 'TEST',
            '--user-agent' => 'TEST',
        },
    },
    extra_capabilities => { 
        'chromeOptions' => {
            prefs => {
                'user-agent' => 'TEST',
                '--user-agent' => 'TEST',
            },
        },
        'goog:chromeOptions' => {
            prefs => {
                'download.default_directory' => '/tmp',
                'user-agent' => 'TEST',
                '--user-agent' => 'TEST'
            },
            args => [ 'headless' ]
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Based on the documentation [custom_args](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::CanStartBinary#custom_args) should be used with `--user-agent`.

Answer (score 1):

[user-agent](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::CanStartBinary#custom_args) can be set through the **custom_args** argument.

To set the [**user-agent**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49565042/way-to-change-google-chrome-user-agent-in-selenium/49565254#49565254) parameter in *Selenium::Chrome* you can use the following solution:

```
my $chrome = Selenium::Chrome->new(
    custom_args => "--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36"
);
```

> PS: Ideally, you should pass a valid [*user-agent*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48454949/how-do-i-create-a-random-user-agent-in-python-selenium/48459249#48459249) following [What is my user agent?](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent)

Comment: Ah, we're getting close.  Using that, I get the following error:
`sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token ``('`
`sh: -c: line 0: ``"/usr/local/bin/chromedriver" --port=57511 --url-base=wd/hub  --user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36  > /dev/null 2>&1 &'`
so it looks like it's not properly escaped.  I put double quotes around the string, and the error went away.  But the user-agent sent did not change.

Comment: It looks like chromedriver doesn't accept --user-agent=XYZ

Comment: @lschult2 Pass an original UserAgent accessing the url https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent

Comment: @lschult2 If you have any query feel free to ask me in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.